# How to start with paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

I am new to Paper.js and i want to implement some examples that they mentioned in this site "http://paperjs.org/examples/". Is this possible to call Paper.js from ruby?Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: You should read up on HTML/CSS and JS first  - seems to me that you don't know the basics just yet so implementing a front-end library without this basic knowledge is not gonna be a slam-dunk

Answer (score 3):

paper.js runs in the browser, not on the server, so you can't really call it from Ruby. You write paper applications in JavaScript (or PaperScript, if you choose to use that). So you would create an HTML file that has script tags for paper.js and your code that uses paper.js. Then the Ruby framework would serve that HTML file to a user on request.